# Convert CamelCase string to uppercase with underscore

Tags: regex

I have a string "CamelCase", I use this RegEx :

```
string pattern = "(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])";          
string[] substrings = Regex.Split("CamelCase", pattern);
```

In `substring`, I have Camel and Case, that's find, but I'd like all in `uppercase` like this CAMEL and CASE. Better, I'd like get a string like this CAMEL_CASE but pease **ALL** with Regex.

Comment: Why **all** with regex? This requirement doesn't seem to make too much sense. I don't even think that this is possible.

Comment: a concat to have this result Camel_Case is ok then

Comment: So, what is the problem left?

Comment: the current result the array substrings, I have these values : "Camel" and "Case", I'd like one string like this "Camel_Case"

Comment: It's to use with Automapper to change the naming convention and the interface ask a Regex

Comment: Once you have substrings, wouldn't `string resul = substrings[0].ToUpper() + "_" + substrings[1].ToUpper();` be enough ? (assuming C# syntax ...)

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a JavaScript implementation.

```js
function camelCaseToUpperCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1_$2').toUpperCase();
}
```

### Demo

```js
printList([ 'CamelCase', 'camelCase' ],
  function(value, idx, values) {
    return value + ' -> '
      + camelCaseToUpperCase(value) + ' -> '
      + camelToTitle(value, '_');
  }
);

// Case Conversion Functions
function camelCaseToUpperCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '$1_$2').toUpperCase();
}
function camelToTitle(str, delimiter) {
  return str.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g, ' $1') // Words beginning with UC
    .replace(/([A-Z][A-Z]+)/g, ' $1')         // "Words" of only UC
    .replace(/([^A-Za-z ]+)/g, ' $1')         // "Words" of non-letters
    .trim()                                   // Remove any leading/trailing spaces
    .replace(/[ ]/g, delimiter || ' ');       // Replace all spaces with the delim
}

// Utility Functions
function printList(items, conversionFn) {
  var str = '<ul>';
  [].forEach.call(items, function(item, index) {
    str += '<li>' + conversionFn(item, index, items) + '</li>';
  });
  print(str + '</ul>');
}
function print() {
  write.apply(undefined, arguments);
}
function println() {
  write.apply(undefined, [].splice.call(arguments,0).concat('<br />'));
}
function write() {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += arguments.length > 1 ?
    [].join.call(arguments, ' ') : arguments[0]
}
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Case Conversion Demo</h1>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, just one point, this regex just replaces the first occurrence. use `str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toUpperCase();` to convert long string

Answer (score 3):

In Perl you can do this:

```
$string = "CamelCase";
$string =~ s/((?<=[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]+)/_\U$1/g;
$string =~ s/(\b[A-Z][a-z]+)/\U$1/g;
print "$string\n";
```

The replacement uses `\U` to convert the found group to uppercase.

That can be compressed into a single regex using Perl's `e` option to evaluate a replacement:

```
$string = "CamelCase";
$string =~ s/(?:\b|(?<=([a-z])))([A-Z][a-z]+)/(defined($1) ? "_" : "") . uc($2)/eg;
print "$string\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sed and tr unix utilities (from your terminal)...

```
echo "CamelCase" | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\1/g' -e 's/^-//' | tr '-' '_' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

If you have camel case strings with "ID" at the end and you'd like to keep it that way, then use this one...

```
echo "CamelCaseID" | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\1/g' -e 's/^-//' | tr '-' '_' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | sed -e 's/I_D$/ID/g'
```

By extending the String class in ruby...

```
class String
    def camelcase_to_underscore
       self.gsub(/::/, '/').
          gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
          gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
          tr("-", "_").
          upcase
    end
end
```

Now, you can execute the camelcase_to_underscore method on any string. Example:

```
>> "CamelCase".camelcase_to_underscore
=> "CAMEL_CASE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string input = "CamelCase";
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, 
      @"(?:\b|(?<=([A-Za-z])))([A-Z][a-z]*)", 
      m => string.Format(@"{0}{1}", 
        (m.Groups[1].Value.Length > 0)? "_" : "", m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper()));
    Console.WriteLine(output);
  }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/qu2bj).

Comment: The result is ok but I need only RegEx, it's to use with Automapper to change the NamingConvention and the interface ask a Regex

Comment: @Kris-I : There is no pure regex solution, this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Perl has a way of changing the case in the replacement, but I don't know of another regex implementation with that feature.

Comment: @MRAB - Really? Show me **single regex** replacement in Perl that would change case and add underscore as well.